# Expected value of infinite sum

Tags: probability

$x_1, x_2, 
\dots, x_n, \dots$ - independent random variables.

Is it true that
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}Ex_i = E(\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} x_i)
$$
?

Answer (score 12):

[Here](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/alcox/lehre/lvss11/rapm/linearity_expectation.pdf) it says:

It can be shown that linearity of expectation also holds for countably infinite summations in certain cases. For example, it holds that:

$E\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i\right]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}E[X_i]$

**if** $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}E[|X_i|]$ converges.

Also [This Book](http://books.google.com/books?id=0bAYl6d7hvkC&lpg=PA23&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q&f=false) says the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, but is this condition important?

Comment: There are cases where your desired equality does not hold.  E.g. flip a fair coin repeatedly.  Let $T$ be the number of flips until the first head.  Let $X_i$ be $-2^i$ if $i<T$, let $X_i=2^i$ if $i=T$, let $X_i=0$ if $i>T$.  Then $E[X_i] = 0$, but $\sum_i X_i = 1$ with probability 1.  For two more examples, see http://algnotes.info/on/background/stopping-times/walds/.