# Infinite sum of random variable~N(0,1)?

Tags: expected-value, fubini-tonelli-theorems

My question is related to this post:
[Linearity of expectation for infinite sums?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166994/linearity-of-expectation-for-infinite-sums)

What makes the switch between expectancy and sum fails?
One is indeed giving 0, the other one infinite.

How shall we then calculate $E \Sigma_1^∞ X_n$?

Comment: There are two general theorems that allow exchange of integrals: Tonelli for positive measurable functions and Fubini for absolutely integrable functions. Tonelli's theorem simply states that the order between two integrations (summation is a form of integral) can be exchanged if the random variables are positive; Fubini's theorem assert the same when the random variables are no longer positive but if we add the hypothesis that their absolute values are summable (i.e. either $E \sum |X_i| < \infty$ or $\sum E|X_i| < \infty$)....

Comment: ...When you have i.i.d. variables, you will always have $\sum E|X_i| = \infty$ and therefore, Fubini's theorem will never apply or if the random variables are positive, then $E \sum X_i = \infty.$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Therefore, you are saying that above expectancy for centered normal distributions will be ∞, which is counter intuitive and does not seem to apply through simulation. Can you please develop further this aspect please?

Comment: No, I am saying that Fubini's theorem will never apply. In fact, I believe $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty X_i$ diverges almost surely for independent and identically distributed random variables. For if it were to converge, then we would have that $X_i \to 0$ almost surely, and we can show that $P(X_i > 1) = c$ and then use Borel-Cantelli lemma to show that $X_i > c$ for infinitely many indices, almost surely, therefore, the sum $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty X_i$ diverges almost surely. In this way, your question is actually nonesense.