# Proof of $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y > t) $ for the infinite case?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $Y$ be a non-negative integer random variable, then show that:

$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y > t) $

**Attempt**:

We can clearly see that $Y = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{Y > t} $.

And by the linearity of expectation for countable sums (see here: [Expected value of infinite sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575974/expected-value-of-infinite-sum))
we can see that if $ \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y > t) < \infty $ , then the above result is shown. But what happens when $ \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y > t) = \infty$, can we somehow show that $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \infty$ in this case, or does this not hold?

Comment: Use Tonelli's Theorem.

Comment: Alternatively, for arbitrary $C>0$ you can choose $N$ such that $\sum_{t=0}^N P(Y>t)>C$ and hence $\mathbb E(Y\wedge (N+1))>C$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you state Tonelli's theorem as an answer. The version mentioned in Wikipedia allows for interchanging integrals in the double integral of a measurable function or interchanging summations in the double summation of non negative series. I can't seem to relate this to the expectation of a countable sum of rvs.

Comment: Any infinite sum is integration w.r.t counting measure and expectation is also an integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments have suggested using Tonelli's theorem, but I'll propose a solution using the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Indeed applying the Monotone Convergence Theorem we get that

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^\infty\mathbf{1}_{Y> j}\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^n\mathbf{1}_{Y> j}\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^n\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{Y>j}]=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}(Y>j).$$